# Unable to resolve rxjs dependency issue

Tags: javascript, npm, rxjs

[image]While trying to install latest version of angular/core, I am facing issue with unmet dependency of rxjs.[image]

I am not sure which version of rxjs is currently installed here!!

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you check what package version you have installed. That `3.10.10` is your npm version not `rxjs` version. Also, using just `npm show rxjs version` will show you the latest version in npm repository, not the installed version.

To see what version of `rxjs` you have use `npm ls --depth=0` that will show you all dependencies defined in your `composer.json` and their version.

I guess your problem is that you don't have `rxjs` in `package.json` and that's why it's complaining about the peer dependency.